# Access data property [Haskell]

Tags: haskell

I have defined a data type called Name which consists of the type synonyms FirstName and LastName.

How would I print out the first name? I understand how to do it in record syntax but not in the default syntax.

```
type FirstName = String
type LastName = String

data Name = Name FirstName LastName

main = do 
      tim <- Name "tim" "lim"
      putStrLn (FirstName tim)
```

I get the following error:

```
test.hs:11:17: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: FirstName :: t0 -> String
   |
11 |       putStrLn (FirstName tim)
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You unpack it, for example with pattern matching:

```
type FirstName = String
type LastName = String

data Name = Name FirstName LastName

main = do 
      let Name fn _ = Name "tim" "lim"
      putStrLn fn
```

But it might be better to use a record for your `Name`:

```
data Name = Name { firstName :: FirstName, lastName :: LastName }
```

Then Haskell will automatically generate two functions `firstName :: Name -> FirstName` and `lastName :: Name -> LastName`, so you can then use that function with:

```
main = do 
      let tim = Name "tim" "lim"
      putStrLn (firstName tim)
```

The main advantage of using record syntax is that you can easily obtain a field from a data constructor, without having to unpack the data constructor, and taking care of all the fields. If the amount of fields grows, it would likely take some extra work to refactor all places where you used the non-record syntax in the first place.

> **Note**: you can not use syntax like `tim <- Name "tim" "lim"` here, since `Name` is not a function that returns a monadic value).

Comment: Great answer as usual!! The reason why I chose not to use record syntax was because I wanted to make a sum type.

Comment: @timothyylim: you can use record syntax with sum types as well, although I agree it is not implemented very nicely, since then the "getters" are no longer per se total.

Comment: @timothyylim For sum types, record fields can become partial functions, so it's better to avoid them. Similarly, `let Constructor x1 .. xn = value` can crash the program if the value has another constructor. For sum types, it's better to use  `case value of Constructor1 x1 .. -> something ; Constructor2 x1 ... -> somethingElse ; ...` or similar pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't define a record visitor, then the only way to visit it's field is pattern matching:

```
type FirstName = String
type LastName = String

data Name = Name FirstName LastName

main = do 
      let tim = Name "tim" "lim"
      putStrLn (case tim of Name fname lname -> fname)
```